# Multiple statements in WITH oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How to execute multiple statement which is using the data prepared by `WITH`.
For example:

```
WITH t1 AS
(
 ....using some table
),
t2 as
(
....using t1 and some other tables
),
t3 as
(
..using t1 and t2 and some other tables
)
statement 1; (let say this is using t1 and t2)
statement 2; (let say this is using t2 and t3)
```

How can I do this in Oracle?

Comment: The `WITH clause` is part of the statement. Are you looking for something like VIEWs ? Or maybe a temporary table ? or PLSQL collections ?

Comment: not going to work this way

Comment: WITH is part of SQL. SQL doesn't have "executable statements".

Answer (score 3):

A subquery factoring clause (`WITH` clause) is part of a single query, where it effectively acts as a single-use view.  If you find you need to repeat the `SELECT` statements in a `WITH` clause on multiple queries you may want to consider defining views for each `SELECT` in the subquery factoring clause to simplify the code.  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
-- Block With
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
with
w1 as
(
select 1 as id
       , '123' as text
from dual
)

, w2 as
(
select w1.*
from w1
)

, w3 as
(
select w2.*
from w2
)
-- End Block With
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

select * from w1, w2, w3;
```

Comment: what if I want to add another statement like `select * from w1;` after `select * from w1,w2,w3;`

Comment: I think it's impossible. You can use `WITH` only in one statement. What do you need to get? Maybe there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the with clause as GIVEN BELOW FOR USE WITH MULTIPLE WITH BLOCKS

```
WITH 
t1
AS (
      SELECT  column1, column2
      FROM   some_tables                  
            ),
t2 as 
(
       SELECT column4,column4
       FROM some tables
)                
SELECT column5,column6 --USE ALIAS OF THE ABOVE BLOCKS YOU HAVE CREATED DOWN AND USE THEM AND SELECT THE IN BASE QUERY
            FROM
            (
                SELECT column1 COLUMN 5,column2 COLUMN 6
                FROM   t1 a
                union ALL
                SELECT column3 COLUMN 5,column4 COLUMN 6
                FROM   t2 a

                )
```

HOPE WILL HELP.